# Android TV Emulator stucks after Android Logo

Tags: android, android-tv

I want to start developing on Google Android TV. I have downloaded Android TV images. But after trying many times it doesn't start.

My System Configuration :

```
1) Windows 7 64 Bit
2) Emulation RAM : 2 GB (1 GB tried)
3) Target : Android 5.0.1
4) Device : Android TV (720p and 1080p)
```

Please let me know, If I messed up something.

[image]

Comment: Try to uncheck the option Snapshot and then start it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first time Any `Emulator` take 15 to 20 minutes. For the better use try `GenyMotion Emulator`

Comment: But I kept open that emulatoer very long time. But still same result. What is GenyMotion ?

Comment: GenyMotion is fast and user friendly emulator for more info visit this link:   https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#installing-genymotion